# merge on two keys from two dataframes with missing rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two sets of data that represent the same information with the same key but with different names of the key. I want to map the keys with 1-1 relationship with inner join (because they are the same ID but reading from different company websites). Here is an example:

Dataset A

[image]

Dataset B (note that row for PO d is missing for ID4):

[image]

Want to map the relationship between "Key" and "ID":

[image]

So that the data set will be connected with this inner joint as:

[image]

How could I do this using python/pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `merge` `dfA` and `dfB` (on "PO Number") to get the relationship between "Key" and "ID"
2. `merge` `dfA` and `mapper` (on "Key") to get the output

```
mapper = dfA.merge(dfB)[["Key", "ID"]].drop_duplicates()
output = dfA.merge(mapper)

>>> output
     Key PO Number    ID
0  Key 1         a  ID 4
1  Key 1         b  ID 4
2  Key 1         c  ID 4
3  Key 1         d  ID 4
4  Key 2         e  ID 1
5  Key 3         1  ID 3
6  Key 3         2  ID 3
7  Key 3         3  ID 3
8  Key 3         4  ID 3
9  Key 3         5  ID 3
```

Or in one line:

```
output = dfA.merge(dfA.merge(dfB)[["Key", "ID"]].drop_duplicates())
```

Comment: Thanks! One PO can be in multiple IDs/Keys sometimes. What is the best way to figure out the merge based on POs? There is no other columns that can separate the same POs in different Keys/IDs. Thanks again!

Comment: What do you mean? Can you edit your question to include a case where this happens? And what should be the output in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Doing chain `merge`

```
dfa.merge(dfb.merge(dfc, how='inner'), how='inner')
```